# aws cdk l1 vs l2 constructs documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I understand the difference between L1, L2 and L3 constructs, but am having trouble matching the contructs for a given service with the documentation. The reason I am attempting to do this is so that I can find a consistent method of comparing different constructs. I can do this with some services but not others.

I know that some services do not yet have higher level constructs, but I am speaking mainly of the ones that do.

Any ideas how I can easily reference side-by-side comparison of L1 vs L2 constructs in a consistent way?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the [AWS CDK API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-construct-library.html)  you can see the full list of constructs for each service. If a construct is prefixed with `Cfn` like `CfnDeliveryStream` for firehose, then it is an L1 construct which maps directly to Cloudformation. Every other construct under the individual resource will be an L2 construct.